# Adding a timer switch to a 3-way set up

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji2eO.jpg)

Hi.  I am replacing our a 3-way light switch for a timer.  I am a bit confused with the wiring on the timer.

I believe I should wire

- BLUE to the black on box 1.
- WHITE to the white on box 1.
- YELLOW to the red on box 3.
- BLACK to the black on box 2.

However, how do I ground the new timer?  I don't have a place for the cooper wire on box 2.  Help!

Comment: So 1 and 2 are the existing 3-way switches as wired originally? Spmething doesn't look right. how about a name and model number for the timer.  The code might not allow the switch being removed if it's by an entrance point.

Comment: Can you post the make and model of your timer please, as well as photos of the inside of both switch boxes involved?

Comment: You do appear to be a bit confused, as what you have drawn is not a three-way switch setup that would work, as well as being cut off to the bottom and right sides of the picture. As already requested, provide actual clear pictures of the wiring in the boxes (don't disconnect any wires, just pull out far enough that details can be seen, and take nice clear focused pictures of it) as well as actual details about your timer, not a vague sketch you drew. [Edit] those into your question. For one obvious thing, if black on box 1 is line, then that's what needs to go to your line connection.